# How to use excel to click a csv download link on a webpage

Tags: html, excel, vba, kibana

I am trying to use excel to download a CSV file from a webpage.

The webpage is a Kibana dashboard, within the dashboard there is a link which will start a download once clicked.

I would like to write an excel macro to click this link and then extract the data from the downloaded CSV file (I think I know how to do this part already) but I have no idea how to click the link.

Can anybody point me in the write direction as I am struggling to find answers through a google/CHATGPT search

I've got as far as opening chrome on the correct webpage.

Thanks in advance

[image]